# References on standard monomial theory

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I am interested in learning about standard monomial theory and Seshadri's program. I find the topic interesting, but I could not yet find a resource which kind of "dumbs it down" enough (a kind of introduction to a layman etc.). Could an expert please point me to some not so difficult to read introductions to SMT, if they exist? Eventually, I would like to understand Littelmann's path models, but I don't mind if the introduction doesn't get there. It will hopefully give me enough information to be able to understand Littelmann's work later on. Many thanks! (By the way, I am currently happy with working over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ for the time being.)

Update: I found Seshadri's book really helpful to understand how SMT developed. Then it was easier to understand how Littelmann's path model came about. I also found some slides by Leonard Hardiman to be really helpful ([http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~hardiman/hardiman_slides_C.pdf](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ehardiman/hardiman_slides_C.pdf)), particularly because they contain some figures, which enables one to see what the path operators do, when applied to a particular path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seshadri wrote a book, "Introduction to the Theory of Standard Monomials" (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-10-1813-8), which is very easy-going, especially in the beginning. But perhaps it does not cover exactly what you're interested in?

Comment: The paper https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-93-86279-11-8_24 and the book *Hodge Algebras* by DeConcini, Eisenbud, and Procesi may be of interest.

Comment: In case Springer changes its URLs in the future, the paper mentioned in [Richard Stanley's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432936/references-on-standard-monomial-theory#comment1114581_432937) is [The Development of Standard Monomial Theory-I](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-93-86279-11-8_24) by C. Musili, in *A Tribute to C. S. Seshadri*, pages 385–420.

Comment: Thank you @RichardStanley and TimothyChow for your additional help ! I now have enough reading material. Seshadri's book, by the way, at least at the beginning, is easy-to-read, which is great. Thank you all!

Comment: Thank you Sam Hopkins for mentioning Seshadri's book. It was really helpful to me, especially the fact that for the special cases studied there (which include $G/P$ with $P$ being a maximal parabolic subgroup), they index the basis using admissible pairs in $W/W_P$, where $W$ is the Weyl group and $W_P$ is the Weyl group of $P$. I found that interesting.

Comment: I should also mention that after reading parts of Seshadri's book, I found some nice slides by Leonard Hardiman to be helpful, because they had some figures (http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~hardiman/hardiman_slides_C.pdf). I guess I need some figures to understand what the path operators are doing. I found this very helpful.